# Include config file after publish with WiX

Tags: c#, .net, wix, publish, wix3.5

**Scenario**:
I have two applications, a Windows Forms App and a Windows Service App. The two applications work together, use same libralies (dll) and share the same configuration file (this file is not the app.config but a custom file).

**Complications:**
I have a website (webforms) where the user will enter information about configuring the software, this information will be saved in the database and from this information will be generated the configuration file. The site should generate build the project with the new configuration file and the page responds to the client's request with a link to download the .msi.

**Problem:**
How to generate an installer from a command line to be called by the web application after generating the configuration file. I researched and found the Windows Installer XML (Wix), but it seems to be necessary to compile the entire project every time someone downloads. It's possible leave the program compiled and only add the configuration file after?

Apretiate any helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Light (the linker in the WiX Toolset) has a feature called "cab cache" which will re-use the cabinet files which are embedded in the resultant MSI. You would use the [arguments -reusecab and -cc to enable this](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/optimizing_builds.html).

You'll still have to re-build the MSI when the user submits your form, but the build will be faster (cabinet generation is usually the longest part of the build process).